# Hive DSN setup connectivity issue

Tags: hive, dsn, azure-hdinsight

While connecting to the HDinsight I am getting the below error while testing the connectivity

**SQLSTATE: HY000[Microsoft][HiveODBC] (34) Error from Hive: SSL_read: error code: 0.**

I am able to connect to my host using a brower.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are two ODBC data sources each for 32-bit and 64-bit, did you configure right one?

Comment: Yeah it was done properly. Anyways I got it resolved long ago though I don't remember what changes did I make